# i'm trying to select max 3 degrees for every class in mysqli

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
(id , s_id  , degree , cid)
```

cid mean class id.
I want select max 3 degrees for every class.
I tried:

```
select s_id,MAX(degree),cid from std_degree GROUP BY cid,degree
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: where's your code ?

Comment: If none of the options in the duplicate link work for you, drop a comment explaining where you got stuck and this can be reopened.

Comment: thank for your help i fixed it 
my code:
$query = mysqli_query($conn," select s_id, cid, degree from std_degree where cid in(SELECT cid FROM std_degree group by cid) order by degree desc limit 9  ");